# Gravityforms custom validation function working, but still submitting the form?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, gravity, gravityforms

I'm using the paid version of gravityforms with wordpress and created custom list fields for picking a start and end date for a reservation.

I want to make sure the date is valid and that the user chose a date in the present day, so I am writing a custom validation.

The way the environment in wordpress (functions.php) is set up is that I am writing a function hooking into a .json file, which locates the form ID and reads which validation function to call.

The problem exists when I test the validation, and the form submits like magic and decides nothing is wrong, even if the fields are empty or random strings instead of dates.

However, when I purposely cause a built-in validation error (say, on another field like "email"), it triggers the 'validation_result' to false and shows me my custom validation errors on the date fields. But ONLY if I cause an error somewhere else in the form, otherwise it runs smoothly.

I know this is a weird question, but I've tried everything and researched my heart out and just can't figure it out.

Here is the code:

```php
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d'){
  $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
  if($d === false) return false;

  return $d && $d->format($format) === $date;
}

function custom_date_validation ($validation_result) {
  $form = $validation_result['form'];
  $today = date("Y-m-d");
  $start_target = rgpost( 'input_39' )[0];
  $end_target = rgpost( 'input_39' )[1];

  if ( validateDate($start_target) == false || $start_target < $today ) {
    $validation_result['is_valid'] = false;
    echo "<pre>"; echo print_r($validation_result, true); echo "</pre>";
    foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
      if ( $field->id == 39 ) {
            //  echo "<pre>Field::"; echo print_r($field, true); echo "</pre>";
                $field->failed_validation = true;
                $field->validation_message = "Start date is invalid! The expected format is 'yyyy-mm-dd'.";
                break;
            }
    }
  }

  if ( validateDate($end_target) == false || $end_target < $today ) {
    $validation_result['is_valid'] = false;

    foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
      if ( $field->id == '39' ) {
                $field->failed_validation = true;
                $field->validation_message = "End date is invalid! The expected format is 'yyyy-mm-dd'.";
                break;
            }
    }
   }
  $validation_result['form'] = $form;
  return $validation_result;
 }
```